# Writing JavaConfig inter-bean dependency with parameter args

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to write these two beans in my configuration class:

```
@Bean
public Foo2 foo2() {
    return new Foo2(foo1("test"));
}

@Bean
public Foo1 foo1(String name) {
    return new Foo1(name);
}
```

But I get an error marker under `name` saying `Could not autowire. No beans of String type found.` Any idea how to wire these beans up properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring needs to know whare to get the name property from. You can use the `@Value` annotation.

Name with a value of "Name"

```
@Value("Name")
```

Name with a value loaded from a properties file

```
@Value("${name.property}")
```

Name with a value loaded from a properties file or a default of "Name" is no property is found.

```
@Value("${name.property:Name}")
```

The full solution would be:

```
@Bean
public Foo2 foo2(Foo1 foo1) {
    return new Foo2(foo1);
}

@Bean
public Foo1 foo1(@Value("${name.property:test}") final String name) {
    return new Foo1(name);
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want multiple instances of the bean with different name properties then you will need to create multiple methods and autowire using a `@Qualifier`:

```
@Bean
public Foo2 bar2(@Qualifier("bar1") Foo1 bar1) {
    return new Foo2(bar1);
}

@Bean
public Foo2 foo2(@Qualifier("foo1") Foo1 foo1) {
    return new Foo2(foo1);
}

@Bean
public Foo1 foo1(@Value("test foo1") final String name) {
    return new Foo1(name);
}

@Bean
public Foo1 bar1(@Value("test bar1")  final String name) {
    return new Foo1(name);
}
```

If you aren't using each `Foo1` instance as a singleton that needs injecting into multiple locations then there is no need to manage it using spring. If this is the case then you can remove the `@Bean` annotation:

```
@Bean
public Foo2 foo2() {
    return new Foo2(foo1("test"));
}

@Bean
public Foo2 bar2() {
    return new Foo2(foo1("test bar2"));
}

public Foo1 foo1(final String name) {
    return new Foo1(name);
}
```

Comment: but what if i didnt want to go the properties file route? How would i implement the first option with `@Value("Name")`

Comment: I ask because there are multiple beans that will use `foo1` and pass in a different arg for name

Comment: I have updated my response with how to use a `@Qualifier` to autowire the correct bean. Alternatively you may not need to manage this bean using Spring